# Template Haskell on Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson, template-haskell

I have a data type like this:

```
module My.Module

data A = A { aFoo :: Integer } deriving (Generic, Show)
```

And I have generic option for Aeson

```
import Data.Char ( toUpper, toLower )

genericOptions :: String -> Options
genericOptions prefix = defaultOptions
  { fieldLabelModifier = dropPrefix $ length prefix
  , constructorTagModifier = addPrefix prefix
  , omitNothingFields = True
  }
  where
    dropPrefix l s = let remainder = drop l s
                     in  (toLower . head) remainder : tail remainder
    addPrefix p s  = p ++ toUpper (head s) : tail s
```

So I can use it like this

```
instance A.FromJSON A where 
  parseJSON = A.genericParseJSON $ genericOptions "A"

instance A.ToJSON A where 
  toJSON = A.genericToJSON $ genericOptions "A"
```

But I realize I could use some template haskell

```
import Data.Aeson.TH ( deriveJSON )
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax ( Dec, Name, Q )

genericDeriveJSON :: Name -> Q [Dec]
genericDeriveJSON name =
  deriveJSON (genericOptions (show name)) name 

$(genericDeriveJSON ''A)
```

It throws an error:

```
Exception when trying to run 
compile-time code:
      Prelude.tail: empty list
    Code: A.genericDeriveJSON ''A
```

It seems `drop l s` on `dropPrefix` returned an empty string meaning the value of `show name` is not string "A". Since I don't think I could inspect the value, anybody knows what is the value?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`nameBase`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.14.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:nameBase) instead of `show` (which is meant for debugging and not core logic).

To see what `show` is doing you can look at the [implementation of `show`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.14.0.0/docs/src/Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.html#line-1226) which is defined as `showName` which is itself defined as `showName' Alone`, to see roughly that it constructs the fully qualified name of your type.